# Redshift Alter query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Below query, we use in Redshift to add a new column for a split function. I would like to know,is this the best way (in performance ) or anything else? Please let me know . Because  I face  performance issues on this query

```
ALTER TABLE schemaname.test ADD COLUMN WASD_3 VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL;
UPDATE schemaname.test
SET WASD_3=SPLIT_PART(details, '_', 1)::VARCHAR
```

Comment: How many rows and columns are in the table?

Comment: 300,000 records and 20 columns

Comment: That's not a huge number (eg millions or billions), so I would recommend you do a few timing tests to see whether you are satisfied with `UPDATE` + `VACUUM`, or whether you need to add extra effort to select into a different table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE` commands are quite inefficient in Amazon Redshift because the whole existing row is marked as 'Deleted' and a new row is appended at the end of the row storage blocks. This means that the data is unsorted until the table is vacuumed.

If the table is large, it would be more efficient to **select the data into a new table** and then either copy the data back to the original table, or rename the tables.